# Office addin manifest file host type

Tags: xml, office365, office-js

Im developing an office addin for both excel and word , and want to have a single addin for both.

The problem is its working in office for web using the host as document for both excel and word, but in desktop word and excel nothing works, and in mac OS document type has to be set as workbook for excel and document for word . Is there any other work around for these problem to set them automatically according to the selected office app

Answer (score 0):

You must have a separate `<Host>` element in the manifest for each Office app that your add-in supports. So, in your case you will have two `<Host>`s, one for Word and one for Excel. Set the type to Document for Word and set the type to Workbook for Excel.

```
…
  <Hosts>
    <Host Name="Document"/>
    <Host Name="Workbook"/>
  </Hosts>
…
  <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/taskpaneappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
    <Hosts>
      <Host xsi:type="Document">
       …
      <Host xsi:type="Workbook">
       …
  </VersionOverrides>
```

Comment: Yes. You can have more than one host in the same manifest file.